# ansible and access to the variable

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I have tow server. I execute this command.

```
- name: get vars
  shell: cat myfile
  register: result
```

On this server, I have access to the variable with `debug: msg=result.stdout`

but I want to access `result.stdout` on another server! is it possible?

**Edite -1**

my hosts file:

```
[master-slave]
192.168.231.102 role=master
192.168.231.92 role=slave
[master]
192.168.231.102
```

my task is :

```
- name: --------get Position ------------
  shell: echo "SHOW MASTER STATUS\G;" | mysql -u root | cut -d ":" -f 2 | grep -v \* | grep -v bin | tr -d " \t\n\r" 
  register: rep_position
- set_fact: 
   rep_pos: "{{ rep_position }}"
  when: role == "master"


- name: -----------From  Master -------------
  debug: msg="{{ rep_pos.stdout }}"  
  when: role == "master"

- name: ---------- From Slave --------------------------------------
  debug: msg="{{hostvars[master].rep_pos.stdout}}"  
  when: role == "slave"
  ignore_errors: true
```

output is :

```
TASK [Master_Node_Galera : -----------From  Master ----------] *******************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.231.92]
ok: [192.168.231.102] => {
    "msg": "638"
}

TASK [Master_Node_Galera : ---------- From Slave ---------------------] ***********************************************
skipping: [192.168.231.102]
fatal: [192.168.231.92]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'master' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/Master_Node_Galera/tasks/main.yml': line 62, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: ---------- From Slave --------------------------------------\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'master' is undefined"}
...ignoring
```

i get error !

**Edit -2**

I tested it, only with ip is worked.

```
- name: ---------- From Slave --------------------------------------
  debug: msg="{{hostvars['master'].rep_pos.stdout}}"  
  when: role == "slave"
  ignore_errors: true
```

output :

```
TASK [Master_Node_Galera : ---------- From Slave ---------------] **********************************************
skipping: [192.168.231.102]
fatal: [192.168.231.92]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['master']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/Master_Node_Galera/tasks/main.yml': line 62, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: ---------- From Slave --------------------------------------\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: \"hostvars['master']\" is undefined"}
...ignoring
```

**ip check**

```
- name: ---------- From Slave --------------------------------------
  debug: msg="{{hostvars['192.168.231.102'].rep_pos.stdout}}"  
  when: role == "slave"
  ignore_errors: true
```

Output :

```
TASK [Master_Node_Galera : ---------- From Slave-----------] ******************************************************
skipping: [192.168.231.102]
ok: [192.168.231.92] => {
    "msg": "638"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `set_fact`. Following simple playbook works (use your own inventory file):

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - shell: cat /etc/hosts
    register: result
  - set_fact:
     result: "{{ result }}"
  - debug:
      var: "hostvars[item].result"
    with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

In some words, `set_facts` register a global variable reachable from all hosts.

I suggest you to use following inventory file:

```
[master-slave]
master ansible_host=192.168.231.102
slave ansible_host=192.168.231.92
[master]
master ansible_host=192.168.231.102
```

Comment: In your case master is not a variable, replace `master` by `'master'`

Comment: See inventory example: use host names and variable `ansible_host` to set ip address. With this example, you can use directly `master`